# Main laptop screen frozen at login page (purple) after login. Other monitors work fine

Tags: boot, nvidia, login, multiple-monitors

**Ubuntu: 18.10**

**Problem**

I have a 3 monitor setup which consists of my laptop, and two monitors attached.

I updated my NVIDIA drivers, and after rebooting my system the following happens:

1. Presented with login screen on the main laptop screen
2. After entering my login details, my laptop screen freezes with the cursor still there.
3. My two other monitors boot up with no problem and are functional.

**Observations**

If I play around with the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F[1-9]</kbd> options, the command line screen and login screen for example (and others) all load up on my main laptop monitor.

**What I've Done To Try and Fix It**

- Reinstalled NVIDIA Drivers (purged then reinstalled).
- Played around with the display settings

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that is experiencing the same problem, I just solved it.

Method:
1. Open Nvidia Settings with `sudo nidia-settings`
2. Select "PRIME Profiles" at the bottom of the list
3. Change to "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" 
4. Log out
5. Log back in. Only one monitor will be active.
6. Repeat steps 1-3, except this time switching back to NVIDIA (Performance Mode)
7. Log out and back in and all your monitors should hopefully be running.